# Is a two and half year Danish Residence Permit considered permanent?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, permits

I am applying for a UK visa from Denmark where I am studying and have a residence permit until December 2019. The visa application asks the following question:

What permission do you have to be in Denmark?

-I have a temporary visa

-I am a permanent resident

-I do not have a visa and I am not a permanent resident

I am not sure which option to check.

Comment: Temporary visa. Permanent resident primarily means you can stay in the country permanently with/without a visa, even though not being a citizen.

Answer (score 6):

Neither of those options are really good descriptions -- your residence permit is specifically not a visa (Per Article 18 of the Schengen Convention [as amended in 2010](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%3A32010R0265) a national visa can be valid for at most one year), but neither is it permanent.

The third option is *literally* correct, but I think I would check "I have a temporary visa", and clarify in free text (you can always attach separate sheets with explanations) that what you have is actually a time-limited residence permit.